# C# BulkCopy WriteToServer odd behaviour

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have something I cannot explain, what could cause this?

Sending data from C# (dot.net 4.5.1.) to the SQL server (2008 - 10.0.1600.22 64-bit Build 6002 Service Pack 2) like this:

```
private int MyBulk(SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy, DataTable dt2save)
        {
            string tblName = "abc";

            /* variable which shows me if save went through or not */
            int myErr = 0;
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tblName;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt2save);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myErr++;
                myLog("a"); /* status check logged in the db */
            }
            myLog("b - myErr = " + myErr.ToString()); /* log myErr in the db */
            return myErr;
        }
```

What I know:

1. the bulk insert works! it saves the data
2. myErr is returned with value 1
3. myLog saves the "b" value, but the "a" value is not saved

After further investigation it looks like the error message in the exception variable tells me that there was a column which is NOT NULL in the database BUT to make things even weirder, the datatable that I am saving does have a real non null INT value on that column.

I would rather not change the datatable to make the column nullable, what should I change? Is it possible this is a bulkinsert problem and maybe I am not the one causing the issue?

UPDATE

1. If SQL Server complained that you made an attempt to store a NULL value in a column that does not allow NULLs, then no doubt that's exactly what happened - The insert went through, that column was the ID column, and NO it wasn't null, it had 548 (int) in it. As for log4net, NLog - makes (some) sense but one of the logs went through so not sure why wouldn't it be OK like this
2. the tables were identical, the bulkinsert went through
3. No I am not calling the method more than once
4. I am testing with **one row** in the datatable

Comment: Essential info missing from this question: the table definition, the actual contents of `dt2save`, the actual contents of the error message rather than your paraphrase. If SQL Server complained that you made an attempt to store a `NULL` value in a column that does not allow `NULL`s, then no doubt that's exactly what happened, but as to the *why*, that needs more digging. Do yourself a favor and log any errors in places *other* than the DB as well (log4net, NLog, take your pick), otherwise troubleshooting connection issues is unreasonably hard (you can't log to a DB that's not accessible).

Comment: The only way I've ever got `SqlBulkCopy` to work is when the tables were identical, YMMV

Comment: Are you calling the method more than once?  Are the datatypes the same in the source and destination tables?  The datatable contains a mapping and maybe the name of the column in the SQL Server and the one in the DataTable do not match.

Comment: Either the insert went through in its entirety or you got an error and it didn't go through in its entirety, but you can't have a successful insert of all rows and also an unrelated exception. Check if your `DataTable` maybe contains some empty (new) row that wasn't inserted, or if the table has a trigger that malfunctioned (although that would require you to configure the bulk copy to fire triggers), or if you specified (or failed to specify) the `KeepIdentity` option. Commenting out the `myLog` calls so they can't confuse the issue by doing more with the DB might also help.